# how to assign the name of list column's as string?

Tags: r

I do:

```
assign('test', 'bye')
test
[1] "bye"
```

now, I have the vector inside **'test**' variable.

I would like to use the string inside 'test' variable as name of a column of the follow list:

```
list(test=c(1:10))
$test
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But I would like to use **'bye'** as NAME (because *'bye'* is wrote inside the test variable)
How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `eval` or `assign` are at all necessary here; their use *usually* (although not always) indicates that you're doing something the hard way, or at least the un-R-ish way.

```
> test <- "bye"
> L <- list(1:10)  ## c() unnecessary here too
> names(L) <- test
> L
$bye
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If you really want to do this in a single statement, you can do:

```
L <- setNames(list(1:10), test)
```

or

```
L <- structure(list(1:10), .Names=test)
```

Comment: For those who don't already know, Ben's first sentence is a reference to `fortune(106)`.  `fortune(181)` is also pertinent. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will be the answer you're looking for?

```
assign('test','bye')
z<-list(c(1:10))
names(z)<-test
```